# JMESPath join output and strip unwanted chars

Tags: json, jmespath

I have the following json;

```
[
  {
    "compartment-id": "CompartmentID-123",
    "defined-tags": {},
    "display-name": "Test-123",
    "freeform-tags": {},
    "id": "ID-ABC",
    "kms-key-id": "",
    "lifecycle-state": "ACTIVE",
  }
]
```

I am looking to join the `id` and `display-name` params into a comma seperate string with `"` and `[]` stripped, like so:

```
ID-ABC,Test-123
```

Closest I've managed to get so far is:

```
oci fs file-system list -c $compart --availability-domain $ad --query 'data[].[id,"display-name"][]' | tr -d '" '
[
ID-ABC,
Test-123
]
```

Wondering if there's a cleaner way of doing this all within JMESPath without piping output to `tr`, `jq`, `sed` or `awk` etc etc

**UPDATE based on input from β.εηοιτ.βε**

So close...

```
oci fs file-system list -c $compart --availability-domain $ad3 --query 'data[0].join(',', [id, "display-name"])'
```

Returns

```
ParseError: invalid token: Parse error at column 13, token "," (COMMA), for expression:
"data[0].join(,, [id, "display-name"])"
```

However playing around with quotes, best I can get is by using;

```
oci fs file-system list -c $compart --availability-domain $ad3 --query "data[0].join(',', [id, 'display-name'])"
Private key passphrase:
"ID-ABC,display-name"
```

I'm beginning to wonder if there's something wrong with my local settings or shell, whereby it's getting confused by the quotes marks?

Comment: Maybe try: `oci fs file-system list -c $compart --availability-domain $ad3 --query 
 "data[0].join(',', [id, display-name])"`

Comment: And if that does not work, you could try: `oci fs file-system list -c $compart --availability-domain $ad3 --query 'data[0].join(\`,\`, [id, "display-name"])'`

Comment: This one was the fix! :)

Spent hours trying to get this point - thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you do have an array, you will first need to target the first element of the array, to get rid of it. Since an array is 0-based, this can easily be achieved via:

```
data[0]
```

which gives

```json
{
  "compartment-id": "CompartmentID-123",
  "defined-tags": {},
  "display-name": "Test-123",
  "freeform-tags": {},
  "id": "ID-ABC",
  "kms-key-id": "",
  "lifecycle-state": "ACTIVE"
}
```

Then, in order to create the string you are looking for, you can use the [`join`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#join) function, that accepts, as parameter, a glue character and array.

You can get the array you look for pretty easily, using [filters and multiselect lists](https://jmespath.org/examples.html#filters-and-multiselect-lists):

```
data[0].[id, "display-name"]
```

which gives

```json
[
  "ID-ABC",
  "Test-123"
]
```

Now we just need to apply the `join` function on top of all this:

```
data[0].join(',', [id, "display-name"])
```

which finally gives:

```json
"ID-ABC,Test-123"
```

---

Additional notes on quoting in JMESPath:

- ```
  'some-string'
  ```

  is a [raw literal string](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#raw-string-literals) and won't be interpreted
- ```
  `some-string`
  ```

  is another form of [raw literal string](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#raw-string-literals) and won't be interpreted
- ```
  "some-string"
  ```

  is a [literal expression](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#literal-expressions) and will be interpreted

So:

```
data[0].join(',', [id, "display-name"])
```

and

```
data[0].join(`,`, [id, "display-name"])
```

are two strictly equals queries.

While

```
data[0].join(',', [id, 'display-name'])
```

has a totally different meaning and would end you with the string `display-name` being the second element of your array, so it will result in

```json
"ID-ABC,display-name"
```

---

All of this based on the JSON structure:

```json
{
   "data":[
      {
         "compartment-id":"CompartmentID-123",
         "defined-tags":{},
         "display-name":"Test-123",
         "freeform-tags":{},
         "id":"ID-ABC",
         "kms-key-id":"",
         "lifecycle-state":"ACTIVE"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explination β.εηοιτ.βε - got very close, but not quite there (update added above)